# Is there any idiom that means "hard to believe"?

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

I can think of "difficult to swallow", but I can't think of anything else. There's got to be more, right?

Comment: Not quite an idiom, but you could say, "it requires a willing suspension of disbelief."  The phrase "suspension of disbelief" is often used when talking about how people accept outlandish things while watching a movie in order to be entertained. Applying it to a real-world situation means that you think that the situation in question is no more realistic than a movie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various idioms:

> Pull the other one. (leg)
>
> Take it with a pinch of salt.
>
> Pigs might fly.